# PHP - Get timestamp from filename and sort in array

Tags: php

I have an example array with filenames:

```
$test_array = array (
'video-start-1537482914-stop-1537483670.zip',
'video-start-1537533156-stop-1537534299.zip',
'video-start-1537534300-stop-1537534630.zip',
'video-start-1537090052-stop-1537091001.zip'
);
```

I want to get start timestamp from each file and then sort them in array. I tried with preg_match but it only works for strings, not arrays. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public function testSort()
  {
    $test_array = array (
      'video-start-1537482914-stop-1537483670.zip',
      'video-start-1537533156-stop-1537534299.zip',
      'video-start-1537534300-stop-1537534630.zip',
      'video-start-1537090052-stop-1537091001.zip'
    );

    usort($test_array, function($a, $b) {
      return ((int)explode('-',$a)[2] < (int)explode('-',$b)[2]) ? -1 : 1;
    });

    foreach($test_array as &$line) {
      echo $line . PHP_EOL;
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php

$test_array = array(
    'video-start-1537482914-stop-1537483670.zip',
    'video-start-1537533156-stop-1537534299.zip',
    'video-start-1537534300-stop-1537534630.zip',
    'video-start-1537090052-stop-1537091001.zip'
);

foreach ($test_array as $item){
    preg_match('/video-start-(.*?)-stop-/', $item, $match);
    $timespan[] = $match[1];
}

//sorts an associative array in ascending order.
asort($timespan);

var_dump($timespan);

?>
```

Output `start timestamp`:

```
array (size=4)
  3 => string '1537090052' (length=10)
  0 => string '1537482914' (length=10)
  1 => string '1537533156' (length=10)
  2 => string '1537534300' (length=10)
```